# Updating quantity in Rails Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord

I'm building a simple inventory app that keeps track of the quantity of an item.

In a basic form I would be updating item_quantity with whatever arbitrary number I type in.

But how would I create a form/code that would allow me to tag on +20 on top of the already existing item quantity?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with jquery/javascript

Something like:

In your view:

```
<%= f.text_field :item_quantity, :id => 'item_quanity' %>
<a href="#" id="increment_item_quantity">+20</a>
```

In javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('#increment_item_quantity').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentVal = parseInt($('#item_quantity').val());
    $('#item_quantity').val(currentVal + 20);
  });
});
```

You'd probably want to make sure the currentVal is a number (since parseInt('') => NaN)

And then submit as usual

Or

If you wanted to do this via a form:

In your view:

```
<%= form_for @item, incr_quantity_path(@item) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller:

```
def incr_quantity
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  # I'd probably move the increment logic into the model
  @item.quantity += 20
  @item.save
  # respond to it however you want
end
```

Or if you want to increment the value by what's entered:

Model:

```
class Item < AR::Base
  ...
  attr_accessible :incr_quantity_by

  def increment_quantity_by
    quantity += incr_quantity_by
  end

  ...
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for @item, incr_quantity_path(@item) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :incr_quantity_by
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def incr_quantity
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @item.increment_quantity_by
  @item.save
  # respond to how you want
end
```